# One duplicate content problems are resolved, how long does take to restore normal rankings instead of being in the "ommited" results?

Tags: google, google-search

My website removed from Google search due to issues with DNS settings (repeated content on wild-card subdomain). Now everything is fixed.

How long does it take to restore site in search results?

Comment: It all depends upon how important Google sees your site, how trendy it is, and how popular it is. Otherwise, it will not be too quick. Depending upon the site size and how often Google visits, it can take a few weeks, or a few months.

Comment: @closetnoc not so popular, about 200 users per day..

Comment: If it is a small site, it can just take a few weeks. Without abusing the feature, you can always use Google Search Console - Fetch as Google, Submit to Index a few pages per day. This will cause the regular googlebot to visit in about 1-2 days in which your page will be processed normally. The Fetch as Google is not really immediate. If the site is small enough, you can do this each day. Generally, it is best to wait.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation there is an option to submit a reconsideration request to Google. To submit a reconsideration request...

1. Sign into your search console account
2. Verify all versions of your site to ensure you have complete and accurate data
3. Visit the manual actions section to see if Google has taken any actions on your site
4. Fix the issues on your site as described by the manual action
5. Review security issues in Search Console for other possible issues with your site
6. Click on "Request a Review" to ask Google to reconsider your site

The reconsideration process that Google follows is...

1. You receive a manual action notification and fix the issues mentioned
2. You document your reconsideration request
3. You address any additional issues
4. You submit the reconsideration request in Search Console
5. You receive acknowledgement from Google (within a few days of submission)
6. Your request is either rejected or approved

If your request is approved then the manual action will be removed from your site.

If no manual action has been taken against your site, in other words the restrictions have been applied algorithmically then there is no real way to remove the restrictions until the Googlebot reindexes your site.

In your reconsideration documentation you should explain the exact quality issues on your site, describe the steps you have taken to fix the issue, and document the outcome of your efforts.

Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35843